# Attempt at remapping evil only remaps some of the keys

Tags: keymap, evil

I'm attempting to change the mapping of evil mode, and I have placed the code below in my `.emacs` file.

When I start emacs some of the keys have been remapped, while others have not

These keys got remapped correctly:

```
e down
n back
s insert
t append
z undo
Z redo
c copy line
v paste
l previous word
```

These keys did not:

```
u up
i forward
y next word
```

I have changed more than what's listed here, but these are what I tested.
The relevant additions to `.emacs`

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "e" 'evil-next-line)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "n" 'evil-backward-char)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "z" 'undo)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "Z" 'redo)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "c" 'evil-yank)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "v" 'evil-paste-after)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "l" 'evil-backward-word-begin)

(define-key evil-motion-state-map "u" 'evil-previous-line)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "i" 'evil-forward-char)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "y" 'evil-forward-word-end)
```

Comment: Could you please remove most of your keybindings from the post and only include the bindings you made for `u`, `i`, `a`, and `y`?  It's hard to expect people to help if they have to wade through a mass of unrelated code.

Comment: @Dan Okay, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `evil-normal-state-map` has higher precedence than `evil-motion-state-map`, so since `u` already has a definition from evil (undo) which is located in `evil-normal-state-map`, the definition added in `evil-motion-state-map` dosen't take effect.

To fix this either remove the keymap of the key in `evil-normal-state-map`

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "u" nil)
```

Or clear all bindings in `evil-normal-state-map`

```
(setq evil-normal-state-map (make-sparse-keymap))
```